# Invoke several functions to the same variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, call

Is there a way to call multiple functions on the same object in JavaScript ?
Something like this :

```
element
    .html('test'),
    .css('color', 'green');
```

Instead of :

```
element.html('test');
element.css('color', 'green');
```

**EDIT :** Thanks for your answers. I didn't know those jQuery functions returned the object it was called on so I could chain them. Although, my question was more like asking an equivalent for, let's say, VB .Net `With` syntax :

```
With object
    .Function1()
    .Function2()
End With
```

Comment: Depends on the method. It has to return the object on which it was called for that to work. The effect is usually referred to as "chaining".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called method *chaining*. It's possible if the method you're calling returns the object reference, and not if it isn't. (But you want to remove the `,` after the first call.)

So it would work with this, for instance:

```
function Thingy() {
}
Thingy.prototype.html = function(value) {
    // ...do something with `value`...

    // return `this` for chaining:
    return this;
};
Thingy.prototype.css = function(name, value) {
    // ...do something with `name` and `value`...

    // return `this` for chaining:
    return this;
};

var t = new Thingy();
t.html('test')
 .css('color', 'green');
```

Most of jQuery's functions, for instance, return `this` for chaining purposes when used as setters (if you're using jQuery, as it seems you might be from the names of the functions you quoted). (When they're used as getters, of course, they return the value you're getting rather than `this`.)

But it won't work if the function *doesn't* return the object reference:

```
Thingy.prototype.html = function(value) {
    // ...do something with `value`...
};

t.html('test')
 .css('color', 'green'); // Fails, because what `html` returned wasn't an object
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery?  The way that works with jQuery is through method chaining.  Each of those functions (html, css) returns a jQuery instance where you can invoke the next method on the instance.

So, long story short, yes, you can do this in any language really, its all about what the function returns so that the next one can invoke a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain operations on a single object like this:

```
element
.html('test')
.css('color', 'green');
```

The caveat is that each method is invoked on the return value of the previous method, so in jQuery where you get an object returned, this can work well, but if you invoke a method with no return value, things can get weird.

The only error in your first code block was the comma between the .html() call and the .css() call.